# How to better manage the copy/cut/paste shortcuts between emacs and the macOS clipboard?

Tags: spacemacs, osx, copy-paste

I'm running `spacemacs` v.0.200.9 on `emacs` v.25.1.1, on macOS 10.11 and 10.12.
And I'm not happy with how the clipboard works between the OS and emacs.

Here's the behaviour I'd expect:

- [X] `Cmd + c` in the OS then `Cmd + v` in emacs pastes whatever was copied
- [X] `Cmd + c` in emacs then `Cmd + v` in OS pastes whatever was copied
- [ ] `d` or `x` in emacs does *not* copy to the OS clipboard

At the moment, any use of `d` or `x` in emacs (yes, this is `evil`) modifies the clipboard. I would like this behaviour to disappear. I would be ready to have special keys combos to copy from emacs or paste in emacs to achieve this.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for your suggestion, I've amended the title to - hopefully - better reflect that it appears it's about shortcuts after all.

Comment: I can't quite tell from your question - do you want to keep the system clipboard separate from the kill ring? If so there's a [good package](https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip) for that.

Comment: @mclear this worked beautifully. If you want to pop it into a proper answer I will mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simpleclip](https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip) seems like what you need. From the docs: simpleclip-mode radically simplifies clipboard handling: the system clipboard and the Emacs kill ring are made completely independent, and never influence each other.